# How to make some cells read-only and some cells read-write in spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, vba

In a spreadsheet, for the cells A to G that I fill data with, I want the cells to be read-write for users (UserA, UserB) other cells i.e. cells H to J should be read-only.
For user C and user D, cells H to J, will be read-write but cells A to G read-only.
With error message that "You not allowed to access this cells"

I will have a sheet 'list of users' in the workbook to contain all users and their cells range to amend.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:G10")) Is Nothing Then 
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Select 
        MsgBox "you not allowed to access this cells" 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: I've created something similar myself and the approach I followed was to give each user a group, and then on their opening the workbook catch their userid, and enable or disable the necessary ranges for their "access level" based on that.  I'd recommend something like that.

Comment: @ dave, Meaning wont need to have a specific sheet for 'list of users'  right? but what about the code amendment how to do it ? can u share it or mail me ze template u have.. pls

Comment: Look into `Range.Locked` and `Worksheet.Protection`, no need to reinvent the wheel here, that's already a feature of Excel.

Comment: @Dave that is easily defeated security theater though.

Comment: Are your users on an Active Directory domain? If so then you can query AD and use the Windows Authentication to identify the user, and have AD manage the security groups. Unfortunately this is way too broad to be answerable here: you need to research and experiment a bit.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yep it is, but for my purposes it was sufficient - OPs mileage may vary on that!